# Как посчитать сумму значений по вертикали в двухмерном массиве\в вложенных списках (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, матрицы

На ввод подается квадратная таблица со случайной длинной\высотой и со случайными значениями, например:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 1
1 2 3 3 2
3 2 1 4 8
7 6 3 2 1
```

Каким образом возможно сложить значения по вертикали (и по диагонали от правого верхнего угла и до левого нижнего) и сравнить их между собой?

P.S.:

В данный момент мой код выглядит так:

```py
def magic_sq(x):
    matrix = [list(map(int, input().split(" "))) for _ in range(x)]
    nums = [i for i in range(1, (x ** 2) + 1 )]
    flag = True
    sum_d = 0
    sum_rd = 0
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(x):
            sum_d += matrix[i][i]
            if matrix[i][j] in nums:
                nums.remove(matrix[i][j])
                flag = True
            else:
                flag = False
                return "NO"

print(magic_sq(int(input())))
```

Comment: А ваш код имеется или вы хотите, чтобы за вас писали? Дайте нам, что нибудь от чего отталкиваться: пример кода, ошибки или что у вас есть еще. Это учебная задача и ее могут закрыть основываясь на этом: [Вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее не стоит задавать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Код имеется, но не дописан до конца

Comment: это совершенно не страшно, добавьте комментарии и сам код в [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1308048/edit), где и почему затрудняетесь. Могут критиковать и возмущаться, но так вы разберетесь быстрее, а тот кто будет решать подобные задачи, будет видеть ошибки и решение

Comment: Код добавил, сам не могу  понять как посчитать диагональ описанную в вопросе, а так же как посчитать сумму столбов и сравнить их т.к. длинна\ширина квадрата не фиксированая